# Change tab color/shadow on Nautilus Elementary with Elementary theme

Tags: nautilus-elementary, elementary-theme

I have a little question, there is a way to change the colour or shadow from tabs on Nautilus Elementary?

For example, I have two tabs opened, but I can't differentiate between both.

I looked up the gtkrc file from this theme, and changed the color from the lines 288,289, but this change the tab colors on others windows and not on Nautilus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem. I solved it in the next file: elementary/gtk-2.0/Apps/nautilus.rc

I have created a new style to display the nautilus tabs on my own. I added this code just after the last style section:

```
style "nautilus-tabs"
{
    bg[NORMAL]              = shade (1.06, @bg_color)   # selected tab entire
    bg[ACTIVE]              = shade (0.92, @bg_color)   # unselected tab

    engine "murrine" { roundness = 4 }
}
```

With this, you can define your own style. Change the values as you want.

At the end of the file change this line:

```
widget_class    "*Nautilus*Notebook"            style "murrine-thin"
```

by this one:

```
widget_class    "*Nautilus*Notebook"            style "nautilus-tabs"
```

Save the file and reload the theme.

Sorry for my english. I could answer you in spanish, but english is more international.

Regards from Spain.